# where to find documentation on how to develop (rails 3) helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, helper

I may be blind but I can't really find any good documentation on how to write helpers for your own views in rails 3.
The kind of answers I'm looking for is:

I have a partial view (say shared/_error_messages.html), where should its helper go, how should I name it, which are the conventions?
How to pass local variables from the view to the helper and vice-versa?

Yeap, so let's say from the basics...
Thanks in advance

Comment: and more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786099/helpers-in-rails/4786280#4786280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the method from _error_messages.html.erb to helpers/application_helper.html.erb, this is a global helper, which means the methods there are available in the whole project.

You could leave it as a partial and load it with

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/error_messages" %>
```

as well.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but what I'm really looking for is some sort of documentation on helpers, in order to fully understand all the process behind. That is still a good advice and a clean solution (as any form has an error_messages form), I'll implement it!

Comment: I guess you've found this article already: http://timeless.judofyr.net/block-helpers-in-rails3. Maybe you have to wait a bit for proper documentation, as Rails 3 is still pretty fresh.

Comment: I've seen it but haven't gone that deep into it before, that helps as well,
I've also found
http://railspikes.com/2008/8/22/how-to-fix-your-rails-helpers

and this one http://www.jason-knight-martin.com/v2/?p=3

and my hero ryan bates with http://railscasts.com/episodes/101-refactoring-out-helper-object (no asciicast available)

but the best doc is (it's normal) in "Agile web development with rails", unfortunately my second edition covers rails 1.2.3
--- thanks again

Comment: In what I've seen there is not a very complete documentation on helpers, yet... I don't know how to return to the view the html I have in a string in a method of the helper. Nor I know if it's possible to use a helper which is not the default one, nor declared in the controller), and this could be useful when I use shared partial view. Whould you please help me out with those last questions?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with helpers, sorry. I found a book which covers the topic though: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/all-about-helpers/ch11lev1sec16 and there are video tutorials on lynda.com especially about that. Hope this helps you further.

Comment: I'd like to recommend also railscasts #40 and #208